# only convert to date cells with data

Tags: python, datetime, pandas-loc

I have a data frame with dates and missing dates:

```
date
2022-02-02
2022-02-03
-
-
```

I need to convert to date only the ones different from '-', I'm using .loc for this but is not working:

```
df.loc[oppty['date'] != '-', 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

> in parse raise ParserError("String does not contain a date: %s",
> timestr) dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: String does not contain
> a date: -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2022-02-02', '2022-02-03', '-','-']})
df1
pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], errors='coerce')
```

[image]

if you want to keep `'-'` change `'coerce'` to `'ignore'`

[image]